# Reading text from standard input till meeting one of exact characters, saving it, then continuing reading until end of line

Tags: c++

I want to deal with basic operations (+, -, *, /) on big numbers. My standard input line will look like `12345678987654322+12334675432142654765786`.
So I want to read first number into one string variable, then sign of operation into another variable and then to continue reading until end of line.

I was thinking about something like this, but it just skips "+" and I have no idea how to include 4 conditions here (+, -, *, /).

```
std::string firstNumber;
std::string secondNumber;

std::getline(std::cin, firstNumber, '+');
std::getline(std::cin, secondNumber);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some work instead of relying on standard functions to do the work for you. What you want can easily be accomplished by reading one character at a time and using a couple of loops

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string firstNumber, secondNumber;
char operation, ch;

ch = std::cin.get();
while (isdigit((unsigned char)ch))
{
    firstNumber += ch;
    ch = std::cin.get();
}
operation = std::cin.get();
ch = std::cin.get();
while (isdigit((unsigned char)ch))
{
    secondNumber += ch;
    ch = std::cin.get();
}
```

This code does no error checking at all, which in a real world program would be a serious problem.

What you are being asked to do is a *parsing* problem. It's a very common thing to do and there is lots and lots of literature on different ways to do parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Read the whole line into a string.

Loop over the string and extract character by character. As long as the character is a digit, put it into the first "number" variable. If it's a non-digit, then check if it's a valid operator, and report failure if it isn't. Extract the second number, character by character, into the second "number" variable.

This way you can more easily detect errors, and also handle spaces between the numbers and the operator.

You can (and I recommend that you do) put the number-extraction into a separate function so you don't have to duplicate the code for it.